# Class has method that shows in intellisense, but gives an error when running it

Tags: python

I'm tring to set the default encoding of my console to UTF-8 so it can display cyrillic letters and accented letters.

Here is my code:

```
from Parser import parser
import sys

print sys.getdefaultencoding()
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Output:

```
ascii
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sergio.Tapia\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BabylonPython\src\TestingGrounds.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```

The weird thing is, when pressing the '.' after sys to see what method it has, setdefaultencoding is shown as a possible choice. Any suggestion on what to do?

Comment: [read docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setdefaultencoding): *This function is only intended to be used by the `site` module implementation and, where needed, by `sitecustomize`. Once used by the site module, it is removed from the `sys` module’s namespace.*

Answer (score 0):

The function `sys.setdefaultencoding()` does exist but [is removed](http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html) from `sys`' dictionary by `site.py` itself.

On my machine, `site.py` contains the following comment:

```
# Remove sys.setdefaultencoding() so that users cannot change the
# encoding after initialization.  The test for presence is needed when
# this module is run as a script, because this code is executed twice.
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html

> This function is only intended to be used by the site module implementation and, where needed, by sitecustomize.